# Problemas con Enlace a Imagen

Tags: python, django

He creado un **modelo** llamado *trabajador* que tiene un **campo** que se llama *firma* donde estoy subiendo la firma digital en una imagen:

```
class Trabajador(models.Model):
    usuario = models.OneToOneField(User)
    dni = models.CharField(max_length=8,primary_key=True)
    apellido_paterno = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    apellido_materno = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    nombres = models.CharField(max_length=100)    
    firma = models.ImageField(upload_to='firmas')
    estado = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def nombre_completo(self):
        return self.apellido_paterno+' '+self.apellido_materno+' '+self.nombres    

    def __str__(self):
        return smart_str(self.apellido_paterno)+' '+smart_str(self.apellido_materno)+' '+smart_str(self.nombres)
```

Tengo un **formulario** llamado *TrabajadorForm* donde utilizo el modelo creado anteriormente:

```
class TrabajadorForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Trabajador
        fields =['dni','apellido_paterno','apellido_materno','nombres','usuario','firma']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TrabajadorForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in iter(self.fields):
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
                'class': 'form-control'
        })
```

Tengo una **vista** para poder **modificar** el trabajador:

```
class ModificarTrabajador(UpdateView):
    model = Trabajador
    template_name = 'modificar_trabajador.html'
    form_class = TrabajadorForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('administracion:maestro_trabajadores')
```

Y la plantilla llamada modificar_trabajador:

```
{% extends "base_administracion.html" %}
{% block cuerpo %}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="page-header">Modificar Trabajador</h1>
    </div>    
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Por favor ingrese todos los campos necesarios.
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form role="form" action="{% url 'administracion:modificar_trabajador' trabajador.pk %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form.as_p }}                         
                    </div>  
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Modificar Trabajador">
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='{% url 'administracion:maestro_trabajadores' %}'">
                            Cancelar
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>         
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="popup"></div>
{% endblock cuerpo %}
```

[image: Modificar Trabajador]

Hasta allí todo funciona muy bien pero cuando le doy click al enlace de la firma me sale un error porque el enlace apunta a:

> http://localhost:8000/administracion/modificar_trabajador/44626821/firmas/vaponte.png/

y no a la ubicación correcta del archivo, quisiera ver si se puede hacer algo para solucionar este problema.
Saludos.

Comment: Hola, ¿cual es la ubicación correcta del archivo?, ¿cómo lo has definido en tu settings.py?

Comment: Hola el archivo está ubicado en la carpeta media/informes dentro de mi proyecto, en mi settings.py tengo definido lo siguiente: MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

Comment: ¿Has intentado hacer [esto](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)? Tienes que hacerlo en la etapa de desarrollo o pruebas

Comment: ¿Te sirvió en enlace que te compartí?, ¿pudiste resolver el problema?

Comment: Tenes el MEDIA_URL definido? porque por el link que pasas la url esta relativa modificar_trabajador.

Comment: Buenas tardes, lamentablemente no pude resolver el problema, a pesar de que seguir algunas de las pautas que me señalaron. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

En el archivo **settings.py** define las siguientes variables:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'images')
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
```

Despues en **app/models.py** modifica el modelo de la firma:

```
firma = models.FileField(upload_to=imageName_Generator)
```

*imageName_Generator* es el nombre de la siguiente funcion (tambien definida dentro del arvhico de models.py):

```
def imageName_Generator(instance, filename):
    import random, string, datetime

    # separas la extencion del archivo y la guardas en ext
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    # guardas en now la fecha y la hora cuando se guardo el archivo (se genero al usuario)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    # personalmente me gusta agregar un string aleatorio para generar nombre aun mas unicos 
    # a los archivos,en esta ocacion estamos generando un string aleatorio de letras y 
    # digitos con una longitur de 5 caracteres
    rdm = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for n in range(5)])

    # finalmente juntamos todo en una sola variable
    finalname = "%s-%s-%s_%s.%s" % (str(now.year), str(now.month), str(now.day), str(rdm), str(ext))
    # y regresamos la ruta donde la guardaremos junto con el nombre y extencion
    return os.path.join('firmas/', finalname)
```

La variable *instance* que recibe la funcion *imageName_generator* es toda la informacion del formulario, en caso de que quieras añadir, por ejemplo, el nombre del usuario al nombre de la imagen.

Muchas cosas ya las tienes contempladas, pero aun asi lo dejo para abarcar todo lo que se necesita para trabajar con imagenes en django.